# ASP.NET Core Identity redirection breaks when using postgres?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side

I've got a small Blazor Server app running with Asp.net Core Identity through EntityFramework 7. I had been using a SQL server, until today when I tried to switch hosting providers. When I try to do the exact same thing with the NpgSql data connector for Entity Framework, the application behaves very strangely. When I log in, the result is a success, but then the redirect from MVC back to the Blazor app times out. If I then refresh the page, I'm still on the Login page, but now signed in, and can use the application as normal. What could be my issue here?

I would share more of my code, but the only difference is going from

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer("<string>"));
```

to

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql("<string>"));
```

My first thought was that there's some part of EfCore that's still trying to use Sql server data providers, but then why would I be correctly signed in on refresh?

EDIT: Just discovered another symptom- apparently, all blazor functions (state change, redirects from methods) are now nonfunctional. It's like if the blazor.server.js file isn't being loaded- but it *is* being loaded correctly, and no JS errors are happening. Feel like I'm going crazy here.

Comment: Have you installed [`Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL) only changing connction provider would not work. In addition, please double check if the postgre sql database has created the identity table accordingly.

Comment: That I have, as well as the base Npgsql package. Identity table looks correct as well, I ran the default migration without changing anything.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed something- the schema in the Postgres database is "public" while the SQL db is "dbo"- could this be part of the issue?

Comment: This might be the one of the reason. Main issue is migration script which may not match with postgres sql with the default migration script.

Comment: Does the migration script you have at this moment is the existing one or you have deleted th older one and after integrating npgsql you have create newer?

Comment: I deleted the old and made a new one when I switched DB providers. I will specify the schema today and try to clean the database and re-run the migration.

Comment: Thanks for the update, try the stepts you have described, if you encounter any further issue feel free to share.

Comment: Unfortunattely it looks like I'm having the same issue, even with the schema specified to dbo. It's so odd- when I create a new user, it gets written to AspNetUsers as it should, and on login the credentials are retrieved as they should- but the actual redirect to the page doesn't happen.

Comment: I have noticed another issue though, which could be a clue.

It seems like the redirect IS happening, the reason it looks like it isn't is because the state change updates aren't happening- None of my moving components are functional when I use the Postgres data provider. This is boggling my mind- again, all I have done is switched the one line of code and installed a couple of NuGet packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT

Turns out I was having a threading issue elsewhere in my program. I was using this code

```
currentUser = UserManager.FindByNameAsync(authState.User.Identity.Name).Result;
```

I had used .Result() here instead of awaiting the method in thinking this would run synchronously- I now realize this is bad practice, as using .Result() in this way is a deadlock waiting to happen. Somehow, this code was fine when using the SQL Server data provider for Entity Framework- My guess is that the cold start time for the SQL server was a bit faster than the Postgres server I'm now using, and because of this the method was taking a fraction of a second longer- then running into a deadlock.

I refactored the code to properly await the method, and now everything works perfectly.